# Why can't I do (flip (+).digitToInt) $ '4' 4

Tags: haskell, syntax

I'm just wondering how `$` works: I was expecting

```
> (flip (+).digitToInt) $ '4' 4

<interactive>:1:24:
    Couldn't match expected type `t -> Char'
           against inferred type `Char'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely '4' 4
    In the expression: (flip (+) . digitToInt) $ '4' 4
    In the definition of `it': it = (flip (+) . digitToInt) $ '4' 4
```

to apply `(flip (+).digitToInt)` to `4 4`, however it didn't work. How come? I've found this works

```
>  (flip (+).digitToInt) '4' 4
8
it :: Int
```

And, I see the type of:

```
>  :t (flip (+).digitToInt)
(flip (+).digitToInt) :: Char -> Int -> Int
```

But, I don't understand why I can't call apply `(flip (+).digitToInt)` explicitly

This confusion comes from the basic observation that

> digitToInt $ '5'

and

> digitToInt '5'

are permitted with the same effect - except that the top has slightly more line noise.

Comment: if you need those parens /and/ `$`, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(flip (+).digitToInt) $ '4' 4
```

is the same as

```
(flip (+).digitToInt) $ ('4' 4)
```

Which of course does not work because `'4'` is not a function.

To get the behavior you want, you can do

```
(flip (+).digitToInt $ '4') 4
```

Or just

```
(flip (+).digitToInt) '4' 4
```

Comment: Why is that? Even this doesn't work `(flip (+).digitToInt) $ '4' $ 4` I would expect that to explicitly show the currying effect.

Comment: actually, that might make sense: this works `((flip (+).digitToInt) $ '4') $ 4`

Comment: @Evan: Because $ has low precedence and is right associative. `foo $ bar $ baz` is parsed as `foo $ (bar $ baz)`, so you're still trying to apply `'4'` as if it were a function.